# CIImage to NSData

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I try my code same as below

```
public extension UIImage {
    func CIBlur(radius: CGFloat) -> UIImage! {
        let imageToBlur = UIKit.CIImage(image: self)
        let blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")

        blurfilter!.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        blurfilter!.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")

        let resultImage = blurfilter!.valueForKey("outputImage") as! UIKit.CIImage
        //let blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
        let cropped:UIKit.CIImage = resultImage.imageByCroppingToRect(CGRectMake(0, 0,imageToBlur!.extent.size.width, imageToBlur!.extent.size.height))

        return UIKit.UIImage(CIImage: cropped)
    }
}


if let img = myImage.CIBlur(10) {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)
    print(data.length) //DATA IS NIL HERE !!!
}
```

As you see the "data" is nil but when I use it in UIImageViewer is working

Comment: @muhammad-adnan looks yes. let me try this solution. is there any other way? or just only CGImage ?